# How to select the the comlumn with the same name (in same level) in a pandas multilevel dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a data frame like:

```
 | Level1_1 |  Level1_2 |  Level1_3
 |----|-----|-----|-----|----|-----
 | A  |  B  |  A  | B   |  A | B
 |----|-----|-----|-----|----|-----
1| 1  |  2  |  3  | 4   |  5 | 6
2| 1  |  2  |  3  | 4   |  5 | 6
3| 1  |  2  |  3  | 4   |  5 | 6
4| 1  |  2  |  3  | 4   |  5 | 6
5| 1  |  2  |  3  | 4   |  5 | 6
```

How to choose all the column named "A" with their corresponding  Level1?

the desire result something like:

```
 | Level1_1 |  Level1_2 |  Level1_3
 |----------|-----------|-----------
 | A        |  A        | A  
 |----------|-----------|-----------
1| 1        |  3        |  5
2| 1        |  3        |  5 
3| 1        |  3        |  5 
4| 1        |  3        |  5 
5| 1        |  3        |  5
```

Comment: please add how the desired dataframe should look

Comment: I edited in the question, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.xs()` method:

```
df.xs('A',level = 1, axis = 1)
```

`'A'` is the name of of your column.

`level = 1` tells pandas that you want `'A'` from `['A','B']` (`level=0` would tell pandas to look in `['Level1_1', 'Level1_2', 'Level1_3']`).

`axis=1` tells pandas that you're doing this with `MultiIndex` columns (instead of rows).

Answer (score 1):

You can select a column using tuple

```
df.loc[:, [('Level1_1', 'A')]]
```

EDIT: To get all the columns names 'A' with the corresponding level, try

```
df.iloc[:, data.columns.get_level_values(1) == 'A']
```

You get

```
    Level1_1    Level1_2    Level1_3
    A           A           A
0   1           3           5
1   1           3           5
2   1           3           5
3   1           3           5
4   1           3           5
```

Consider this dataframe with 3 levels,

```
    Level_1_0
    Level1_1    Level1_2    Level1_3
    A           A           A
0   1           3           5
1   1           3           5
2   1           3           5
3   1           3           5
4   1           3           5
```

The solution with get_level_values will still work by providing the correct level like this:

```
data.iloc[:, data.columns.get_level_values(2) == 'A']
```

Comment: is the "1" in the  data.columns.get_level_values(1) == 'A' indicate the level of index?

Comment: Thats right, check this out : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html

Comment: The advantage of using get_level_values is that it works for any level of multi-index

Answer (score 1):

You can use slice. The code below will choose all the column named "A" with their corresponding Level1

```
df.loc[:,(slice(None), 'A')]
Out[16]: 
  level_1 level_2 level_3
        A       A       A
0       1       3       5
1       1       3       5
2       1       3       5
3       1       3       5
4       1       3       5
```

Comment: thank you, but for a bit further - how can i use this method for higher level of data frame

Comment: slice is very flexible, take a look at the documentation. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html

Answer (score 1):

You need [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) with parameter `drop_level=False` - see also [cross-section](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#cross-section):

```
df = df.xs('A',level=1, axis=1, drop_level=False)
print (df)
  Level1_1 Level1_2 Level1_3
         A        A        A
1        1        3        5
2        1        3        5
3        1        3        5
4        1        3        5
5        1        3        5
```

You can also specify the `axis` argument to `.loc` to interpret the passed slicers on a single axis:

```
df = df.loc(axis=1)[:, 'A']
print (df)
  Level1_1 Level1_2 Level1_3
         A        A        A
1        1        3        5
2        1        3        5
3        1        3        5
4        1        3        5
5        1        3        5
```

and last solution [using slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df = df.loc[:, idx[:, 'A']]
print (df)
  Level1_1 Level1_2 Level1_3
         A        A        A
1        1        3        5
2        1        3        5
3        1        3        5
4        1        3        5
5        1        3        5
```